# Is Scala Truly Asynchronous

Tags: node.js, scala, asynchronous, java-8, nonblocking

These days I am looking into Scala for writing a non-blocking Restful API. I have already done a couple of projects in node.js and was curious to look into Scala this time around.

My findings till now have been that its impossible to write 100% asynchronous code in Scala as most of the underlying code is blocking. You can find tutorials on how to use JDBC in Scala application for database connectivity. JDBC being blocking means any application using it can't work in a single threaded environment as it will queue up all other requests while waiting for DB response.Play Framework recommends increasing thread pool when using blocking APIs which means we are going back to from where we started.

As for node.js, nearly all available modules have been written asynchronously. Specially all of the database connectors and file handlers read/write asynchronously keeping in mind that nothing can block when you have a single thread. Yet I see people favoring Scala over node.js for its type safety and computation power while being asynchronous. But the asynchronous behavior doesn't reflect in most of the tutorials and resources available online.

My question is, is it only me who is failing to understand this or is there a confusion in JVM world what asynchronous actually means?

**Update:**

I know JDBC being synchronous does not make Scala synchronous but I have seen people argue that their API is non-blocking yet they are using synchronous libraries. Also, how is it possible to write a non-blocking application in Scala if most of the drivers and libraries are still blocking. Even if there are alternatives this means you have to be very careful when using a library to check its internals to see if its blocking or non-blocking which is not the case for node.js.

Comment: There's a confusion about JDBC being async vs Scala in this question.

Comment: Neither Scala or Node.js are async by nature, but their libs are. Considering JDBC, as low level that's sync, but there are async lib above (Slick, Anorm).

Comment: Yes JDBC is synchronous but I see tutorials for writing non-blocking server yet they are using JDBC or handling files in a blocking way.

Comment: Non-blocking (in the Typesafe sense) == threads aren't being held by inactive processes. There is no waiting or sleeping. Instead, the thread is being assigned to those who need it at the moment.

Comment: Yes but if the only thread that exists made a query to DB and waits for the response then there is no other thread to handle other requests. In this case the thread is most probably in a waiting state.

Comment: Waiting for a response means that it's blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible (I would even say easy) to write asynchronous applications in Scala (and Java) **but you have to be careful** about third party libraries, know which of the API:s that are blocking and which are asynchronous.

As an example there is both blocking and non-blocking IO API:s provided with the Java standard library.

JDBC is another common example of an API that is inherently blocking, if you want to write 100% asynchronous applications you just have to use a different client for your database.

One big difference from node.js is that you can actually handle having blocking API:s together with asynchronous stuff. This is possible since we have multi threading in the JVM and can run the blocking stuff in a separate thread pool that is tuned for that task. So for if we have 8 possible blocking database connections we can run those on a thread pool with 8 threads without blocking any asynchronous code on the "regular" thread pool.

As a side note, that we have concurrency also allows us to have one thread per core to run asynchronous code in parallell rather than one for the entire vm.

Comment: This kind of freaks me out as now I have to worry about which parts of my application need separate thread pools as they are blocking, specially if I haven't written the library. This also means I need a rigorous concurrency test to see how each component of the application will behave under load specially if any of the data source stops responding for even a short while.

Comment: I assume that you are implicitly comparing JVM and Node.js here? Your point is valid but the comparison is not: The problem is that Node.js has only one actual thread - JVM can have as many as the system requires. So JVM makes things more complex but this is because it is much more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to write fully asynchronous code in Scala. There are lots of reactive libraries and TypeSafe puts a lot of efforts into providing a reactive platform/ecosystem. To convince yourself, just have a look at [awesome scala](https://github.com/lauris/awesome-scala) and search "Reactive", or follow [TypeSafe webinars](https://www.typesafe.com/blog/Webinar).

I don't know Node.js, but i think you can write such a blocking function :

```
function aBlockingFunction() {
  while(resourceNotAvailable) {
  }
  ...
}
```

Scala will not magically make synchronous code asynchronous, but it will provide you all you need to write fully a asynchronous one ([Futures](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future)/[Promises](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Promise), [Actors](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.12/#akka.actor.Actor), Streams, ...).

Being asynchronous does not mean being single threaded, it means you keep doing useful thinks while waiting for replies. Play is designed to be fully asynchronous but you can still write blocking code (like calling a synchronous API). But if you write fully asynchronous one, yes you can run a single thread. To do that, just use Futures/Actors/...

Scala concurrency is modelled that way: there is a (actually many) thread pool which correspond to parallel execution and there are tasks to do (Futures/Actors/...). Tasks are dispatched on available threads. When a task need to wait for a reply or yield, the thread is assigned to another tasks which is ready and so on. Your computation that appears to be "single threaded" is actually made of a lot of small coordinated mini-tasks that run on whichever thread is available (and usually not the same).

By default, [Play thread pools have as many threads as available processors](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ThreadPools). This is perfect is your code is asynchronous as a thread will never go idle (when a task go idle, another one will replace it). But when performing blocking operations, you'll block the tread and so you'll have one processor less until the operation finishes.

This is the well known co-operative/pre-emptive problem. Co-operative is lighter and faster as it does not require to save that much contexts (it can be as light as a function call) but one tasks can block others.

That's why, when using a lot of blocking calls, Play recommends to increase the thread pool (you should actually create another thread pool dedicated to blocking operations). You should ideally allocate "number_of_simultaneous_blocking_operations + number_of_possible_parallel_executions" threads so that there is always a thread available for a ready task.

My advice is: go for asynchronous mechanisms (Futures/Actors/Streams/...) and reactive libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Scala is built on top of the JVM and most of the code in the JVM world including JDBC was written for Java. Scala tries to encourage you to write non-blocking code using Futures or Akka Actors but obviously just like in any programming language you can do what you wish.

So for your question, no scala is not 100% non-blocking I mean you can even use synchronized blocks from Java if you wish to. But you are encouraged and thought to think about the disadvantages of blocking code and how to avoid it (immutables, stateless etc) and you are supported to write non-blocking code by features in the language (monads for transforming data instead of changing it in a mutable way).